# Sort and group a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

How can I sort and group this list of dictionaries into a nested dictionary which I want to return via an API as JSON.

Source Data (list of permissions):

```
[{
    'can_create': True,
    'can_read': True,
    'module_name': 'ModuleOne',
    'module_id': 1,
    'role_id': 1,
    'end_point_id': 1,
    'can_update': True,
    'end_point_name': 'entity',
    'can_delete': True,
}, {
    'can_create': True,
    'can_read': True,
    'module_name': 'ModuleTwo',
    'module_id': 2,
    'role_id': 1,
    'end_point_id': 4,
    'can_update': True,
    'end_point_name': 'financial-outlay',
    'can_delete': True,
},{
    'can_create': True,
    'can_read': True,
    'module_name': 'ModuleOne',
    'module_id': 1,
    'role_id': 1,
    'end_point_id': 2,
    'can_update': True,
    'end_point_name': 'management-type',
    'can_delete': True,
}, {
    'can_create': True,
    'can_read': True,
    'module_name': 'ModuleOne',
    'module_id': 1,
    'role_id': 1,
    'end_point_id': 3,
    'can_update': True,
    'end_point_name': 'ownership-type',
    'can_delete': False,
}, {
    'can_create': True,
    'can_read': True,
    'module_name': 'ModuleTwo',
    'module_id': 2,
    'role_id': 1,
    'end_point_id': 5,
    'can_update': True,
    'end_point_name': 'exposure',
    'can_delete': True,
}]
```

I want to transform that into a nested dicitonary object for return with an API as JSON. Here's the expected output:

```
{
    "role_id": 1,
    "modules": [{
            "module_id": 1,
            "module_name": "ModuleOne",
            "permissions": [{
                "end_point_id": 1,
                "end_point_name": "entity",
                "can_create": False,
                "can_read": True,
                "can_write": True,
                "can_delete": True
            }, {
                "end_point_id": 2,
                "end_point_name": "management-type",
                "can_create": False,
                "can_read": True,
                "can_write": True,
                "can_delete": True
            }, {
                "end_point_id": 3,
                "end_point_name": "ownership-type",
                "can_create": False,
                "can_read": True,
                "can_write": True,
                "can_delete": True
            }, ]
        }, {
            "module_id": 2,
            "module_name": "ModuleTwo",
            "permissions": [{
                "end_point_id": 4,
                "end_point_name": "financial-outlay",
                "can_create": False,
                "can_read": True,
                "can_write": True,
                "can_delete": True
            }, {
                "end_point_id": 5,
                "end_point_name": "exposure",
                "can_create": False,
                "can_read": True,
                "can_write": True,
                "can_delete": True
            }, ]
        },

    ]
}
```

It looked trivial until I spent more time that I would expect trying to bend my mind around it. I've attempted so many options with non of them working. Here's the last attempt.

```
# Get user role
user_roles = get_user_roles()  # List of roles e.g. [{'role_id':1, role_name: 'role_one'}, {'role_id':2, role_name: 'role_two'}]

for role in user_roles:
    role_id = role['role_id']
    role_name = role['role_name']

    # Fetch Role Permissions
    role_permissions = get_role_permissions(role_id)  # List of permissions as seen above
    sorted_role_permissions = sorted(role_permissions, key=itemgetter('module_id'))  # sort dictionaries in list by 'module_id'

    modules_list = []
    permissions_list = []
    previous_module_id = 0
    is_first_loop = True
    for role_permission in sorted_role_permissions:

        module_id = role_permission['module_id']
        module_name = role_permission['module_name']
        end_point_id = role_permission['end_point_id']
        end_point_name = role_permission['end_point_name']

        if is_first_loop:
            print(0)
            is_first_loop = False
            previous_module_id = module_id
            print('end_point_name 0 {}'.format(end_point_name))
            permissions = {'end_point_id': end_point_id, 'end_point_name': end_point_name,
                           'can_create': role_permission['can_create'],
                           'can_read': role_permission['can_read'],
                           'can_update': role_permission['can_update'],
                           'can_delete': role_permission['can_delete']
                           }
            permissions_list.append(permissions)
            if len(sorted_role_permissions) == 1:
                # If there is only one permission in the role, end the loop
                modules_dict = {'module_id': module_id, 'module_name': module_name,
                                'permissions': permissions_list}
                modules_list.append(modules_dict)
                break

        else:

            if module_id == previous_module_id:
                # As long as the current module_id and the previous_module_id are the same, add to the same list

                print(1)
                permissions = {'end_point_id': end_point_id, 'end_point_name': end_point_name,
                               'can_create': role_permission['can_create'],
                               'can_read': role_permission['can_read'],
                               'can_update': role_permission['can_update'],
                               'can_delete': role_permission['can_delete']
                               }
                permissions_list.append(permissions)

            else:

                print(2)
                modules_dict = {'module_id': module_id, 'module_name': module_name,
                                'permissions': permissions_list}
                modules_list.append(modules_dict)
                permissions_list = []
                permissions = {'end_point_id': end_point_id, 'end_point_name': end_point_name,
                               'can_create': role_permission['can_create'],
                               'can_read': role_permission['can_read'],
                               'can_update': role_permission['can_update'],
                               'can_delete': role_permission['can_delete']
                               }
                permissions_list.append(permissions)
                previous_module_id = module_id

    if modules_list:
        roles.append({'role_id': role_id, 'role_name': role_name, 'modules': modules_list})
```

Comment: What should the result be if there are multiple roles? Can modules have the same id if their role is different?

Comment: If there are multiple roles, then you will have another "list of dictionaries" with the top node being 'role_id & role_name". But please note that to get the list of permissions, am passing the role_id `(get_role_permissions(role_id)` which means that the role_permissions wouldn't have more than one role in it. And yes, modules can be assigned to more than one role but again, remember we are passing `role_id` which takes care of that as explained above. As an example, the sample data give in the `list of permissions` above has got one `role_id` in all dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TADA!

```
from itertools import groupby

def group_by_remove(permissions, id_key, groups_key, name_key=None):
    """
    @type permissions: C{list} of C{dict} of C{str} to C{object}
    @param id_key: A string that represents the name of the id key, like "role_id" or "module_id"
    @param groups_key: A string that represents the name of the key of the groups like "modules" or "permissions"
    @param name_key: A string that represents the name of the key of names like "module_name" (can also be None for no names' key) 
    """
    result = []
    permissions_key = lambda permission: permission[id_key]
    # Must sort for groupby to work properly
    sorted_permissions = sorted(permissions, key=permissions_key)
    for key, groups in groupby(sorted_permissions, permissions_key):
        key_result = {}
        groups = list(groups)
        key_result[id_key] = key
        if name_key is not None:
            key_result[name_key] = groups[0][name_key]
        key_result[groups_key] = [{k: v for k, v in group.iteritems() if k != id_key and (name_key is None or k != name_key)} for group in groups]
        result.append(key_result)
    return result

def change_format(initial):
    """
    @type initial: C{list}
    @rtype: C{dict} of C{str} to C{list} of C{dict} of C{str} to C{object}
    """
    roles_group = group_by_remove(initial, "role_id", "modules")[0]
    roles_group["modules"] = group_by_remove(roles_group["modules"], "module_id", "permissions", "module_name")
    return roles_group

change_format(role_permissions)
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Hehe. It's annoyingly mind bending... Am on mobile will test when I get to a PC.

Comment: Am getting an error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` on this line `key_result[groups_key] = [{k: v for k, v in group.iteritems() if k != id_key and (name_key is None or k != name_key)} for group in groups]`. Am using the role_permissions in this question so the data is the same.

Comment: You're on python 3? I used python 2. In python 3 I think it should be `group.items()` instead of `group.iteritems()`

Answer (score 2):

PyFunctional is pretty good at list manipulation.

```
from pprint import pprint
from functional import seq
input = [...]  # taken from your example
output =(
    seq(input)  # convert regular python list to Sequence object

    # group by role_id
    .map(lambda e: (e.pop('role_id'), e)).group_by_key()

    # start building role dict
    .map(lambda role_modules: {
        "role_id": role_modules[0],
        "modules": seq(role_modules[1])
                   # group by (module_id, module_name)
                   .map(lambda e: ( (e.pop('module_id'), e.pop('module_name')), e) ).group_by_key()

                   # start building module/permissions dict
                   .map(lambda module_permissions: {
                       "module_id": module_permissions[0][0],
                       "module_name": module_permissions[0][1],
                       "permissions": module_permissions[1]
                   })
                   # sort by module_id, convert Seq obj to regular list
                   .sorted(key=lambda m:m['module_id']).to_list()
    })
    # sort by role_id, convert Seq obj to regular list
    .sorted(key=lambda r:r['role_id']).to_list()
)

pprint(output)
```

**RESULT**

```
[{'modules': [{'module_id': 1,
               'module_name': 'ModuleOne',
               'permissions': [{'can_create': True,
                                'can_delete': True,
                                'can_read': True,
                                'can_update': True,
                                'end_point_id': 1,
                                'end_point_name': 'entity'},
                               {'can_create': True,
                                'can_delete': True,
                                'can_read': True,
                                'can_update': True,
                                'end_point_id': 2,
                                'end_point_name': 'management-type'},
                               {'can_create': True,
                                'can_delete': False,
                                'can_read': True,
                                'can_update': True,
                                'end_point_id': 3,
                                'end_point_name': 'ownership-type'}]},
              {'module_id': 2,
               'module_name': 'ModuleTwo',
               'permissions': [{'can_create': True,
                                'can_delete': True,
                                'can_read': True,
                                'can_update': True,
                                'end_point_id': 4,
                                'end_point_name': 'financial-outlay'},
                               {'can_create': True,
                                'can_delete': True,
                                'can_read': True,
                                'can_update': True,
                                'end_point_id': 5,
                                'end_point_name': 'exposure'}]}],
  'role_id': 1}]
```

Comment: Am in python3.5. Am getting error `tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in python3` for the lines `(role_id, modules)` and `((module_id, module_name), permissions)`. Do you have a workaround?

Comment: Updated the answer for Python3.  Sorry I missed the python3 tag.  [Python3 removed tuple parameter unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).  Unfortunately the code became less readable.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Tested and it works. For the sake of marking the correct answer, I will go with Ella's answer as it doesn't require an external package though I have to admit your option is much more compact. I wonder if it performs any faster though

Comment: np.  It was mostly for fun.  Performance wise it's 5 times slower than Ella's.  The functional style code is close to how we write Apache Spark applications that run in cluster environment.   If the size of data was huge and ok to use a cluster computers there might be a chance that my code would run faster. haha