# Sort and Flatten List/Dictionary of Data

Tags: python, sql, sorting, python-itertools

I feel like this has to be fairly easy but find myself nesting too many loops for sanity.

Given a list of dictionaries like this

```
[{'id': 101, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '',    'value3': '',    'value4': 'no' },
 {'id': 102, 'value1': '',    'value2': 'yes', 'value3': '',    'value4': 'no'},
 {'id': 103, 'value1': 'no',  'value2': '',    'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''   },
 {'id': 104, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '',    'value3': 'no',  'value4': 'yes'},
 {'id': 105, 'value1': '',    'value2': 'yes', 'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''   },
 {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '',    'value3': '',    'value4': ''   }]
```

I want to create lists of dictionaries where the values either match or are empty.

Desired result (lists of lists but could be a list/dict/whatever, note there are duplicates)

```
[[{'id': 101, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '',    'value3': '',    'value4': 'no' },
  {'id': 102, 'value1': '',    'value2': 'yes', 'value3': '',    'value4': 'no' },
  {'id': 105, 'value1': '',    'value2': 'yes', 'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''   },
  {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '',    'value3': '',    'value4': ''   }],

 [{'id': 102, 'value1': '',    'value2': 'yes', 'value3': '',    'value4': 'no' },
  {'id': 103, 'value1': 'no',  'value2': '',    'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''   },
  {'id': 105, 'value1': '',    'value2': 'yes', 'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''   }],

 [{'id': 104, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '',    'value3': 'yes', 'value4': 'yes'},
  {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '',    'value3': '',    'value4': ''   }]]
```

There has to be some way to do this using itertools groupby I would think but I can't quite figure it out. This answer [Sort and group a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989777/sort-and-group-a-list-of-dictionaries) was pretty similar but not exactly what I need. It would be pretty simple if it were just one value but multiples are giving me fits. Any thoughts?

EDIT: So this hideous construction works. The thing is I have at least 13 fields (value1...value13) to do this on so need to make this more flxible.

```
list = [ {'id': 101, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '',    'value3': '',    'value4': 'no' },
         {'id': 102, 'value1': '',    'value2': 'yes', 'value3': '',    'value4': 'no' },
         {'id': 103, 'value1': 'no',  'value2': '',    'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''   },
         {'id': 104, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '',    'value3': 'no',  'value4': 'yes'},
         {'id': 105, 'value1': '',    'value2': 'yes', 'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''   },
         {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '',    'value3': '',    'value4': ''   }]

final_list = []
matched = False
for dict1 in list:
    sub_list = []
    for dict2 in list:
        if dict1 == dict2:
            continue
        print(dict1)
        print(dict2)
        print('---')
        if ((dict1['value1'] == dict2['value1'] or dict1['value1'] == '' or dict2['value1'] == '') and
            (dict1['value2'] == dict2['value2'] or dict1['value2'] == '' or dict2['value2'] == '') and
            (dict1['value3'] == dict2['value3'] or dict1['value3'] == '' or dict2['value3'] == '') and
            (dict1['value4'] == dict2['value4'] or dict1['value4'] == '' or dict2['value4'] == '')):
            # so these two match
            # now make sure it doesn't conflict with the other entries already there
            if sub_list:
                subsublist = sub_list
                sub_conflict = False
                for dict3 in subsublist:
                    if dict2 == dict3:
                        continue
                    print("    ",dict2)
                    print("    ",dict3)
                    if ((dict2['value1'] == dict3['value1'] or dict2['value1'] == '' or dict3['value1'] == '') and
                        (dict2['value2'] == dict3['value2'] or dict2['value2'] == '' or dict3['value2'] == '') and
                        (dict2['value3'] == dict3['value3'] or dict2['value3'] == '' or dict3['value3'] == '') and
                        (dict2['value4'] == dict3['value4'] or dict2['value4'] == '' or dict3['value4'] == '')):
                        print('no conflict for this one')
                    else:
                        sub_conflict = True
                if not sub_conflict:
                    sub_list.append(dict2)
            else:
                sub_list.append(dict1)
                sub_list.append(dict2)
                print('appending both to list')
    #if not matched and [dict1 not in list3 for list3 in final_list]:
    # if not matched:
    #     print('not matched')
    #     sub_list=[dict1]
    sorted_list = sorted(sub_list, key=lambda k: k['id'])
    print('-------------------------------')
    final_list.append(tuple(sorted_list))

#print(*final_list)

final_final_list = []
for list in final_list:
    if list not in final_final_list:
        final_final_list.append(list)

for list in final_final_list:
    # print(list)
    for list2 in list:
        print(list2)
    print('')
```

Comment: How exactly are you grouping the dictionaries?

Comment: your question is not clear. can you explain how you getting the expected output from the input you posted

Comment: I am not actually getting that result, that's just an example of what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list of dicts is called `dict_list`, does this

```
from itertools import product

values = ['yes', 'no']
num_value_fields = 4
keys = [f'value{i}' for i in range(1, num_value_fields + 1)]
results = []
for combo in product(values, repeat=num_value_fields):
    result = [d for d in dict_list if all(d[key] in {value, ''}
                                          for key, value in zip(keys, combo))]
    if len(result) > 1:
        results.append(result)
```

produce your expected output

```
[[{'id': 105, 'value1': '', 'value2': 'yes', 'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''},
  {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': ''}],
 [{'id': 101, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': 'no'},
  {'id': 102, 'value1': '', 'value2': 'yes', 'value3': '', 'value4': 'no'},
  {'id': 105, 'value1': '', 'value2': 'yes', 'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''},
  {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': ''}],
 [{'id': 104, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': 'no', 'value4': 'yes'},
  {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': ''}],
 [{'id': 101, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': 'no'},
  {'id': 102, 'value1': '', 'value2': 'yes', 'value3': '', 'value4': 'no'},
  {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': ''}],
 [{'id': 101, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': 'no'},
  {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': ''}],
 [{'id': 104, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': 'no', 'value4': 'yes'},
  {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': ''}],
 [{'id': 101, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': 'no'},
  {'id': 106, 'value1': 'yes', 'value2': '', 'value3': '', 'value4': ''}],
 [{'id': 103, 'value1': 'no', 'value2': '', 'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''},
  {'id': 105, 'value1': '', 'value2': 'yes', 'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''}],
 [{'id': 102, 'value1': '', 'value2': 'yes', 'value3': '', 'value4': 'no'},
  {'id': 103, 'value1': 'no', 'value2': '', 'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''},
  {'id': 105, 'value1': '', 'value2': 'yes', 'value3': 'yes', 'value4': ''}]]
```

?

Comment: It's really close! The only issue would be duplicates (101, 104 and 104, 101) and that some subsets are included in others, as in 105, 106 is one set and 101, 102, 105, 106 but that is really easy to clean up. Thanks a lot for this! I was able to get it working with 55 lines of code versus your 8.